# Converting Shapefile to DGN dos not display all geometry in MicroStation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, microstation, dgn

I am trying to convert a shapefile of FEMA floodplains from shapefile format to DGN format for use in MicroStation. 
I'm using the "Export to CAD" tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4

[image: ARCGIS Toolbox Snip]

The conversion appears to go well, and the resultant DGN draws just fine in ArcGIS. However, when loaded into MicroStation, much of the geometry does not appear. Its like in MicroStation the geometry does not exist.

It appears that any geometry with an attribute greater than 0 in the "Shape_Are" attribute field of the original shapefile gets ignored.

Can anyone tell my why these polygons are not being brought into MicroStation? Since the DGN draws correctly in ArcGIS, I assume that the geometry is written into the DGN but is not being recognized by MicroStation. 
I am using:

- MicroStation Select Series 2
- ArcGIS Desktop Basic 10.4

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is the color of the features because MicroStation defaults to white features on a black background, and most other systems are black on white.

I've converted the other way before (MicroStation -> Another Format) and couldn't figure out where the features were - they were white features on a white background!

If they are specifically polygon/area features, check the view attributes to make sure Fill is turned on.

Also check the Level Manager to see a) that the levels are actually turned on! b) whether symbology is ByLevel, rather than a specific color, c) what element usage is (it should tell you how many of each element are on a layer).

If the layer is on, and there are elements, then I think it's likely to be a symbology issue.